# How to write multilevel conditions in where clause

Tags: sql-server

Lets assume, I have one column 'Rate' and rows have to be fetched on basis of below criteria. 
Below CHARS are nothing but columns.

1. if X>Y then fetch Rate
2. if A>B then

   - if C>D then fetch Rate
   - if E>F then

     - if G>H then fetch Rate
     - if I>J then fetch Rate
     - if K>L then

       - if M>N THEN fetch Rate

I am stuck at, how to write multilevel conditions in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not at all sure I've gotten the right end of the stick, but it sounds like you just want to combine multiple conditions in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    X>Y OR
    (
       A>B AND
       (
          C>D OR
          (
              E>F AND
              (
                 G>H OR
                 I>J OR
                 (K>L AND M>N)
              )
          )
       )
    )
```

Not all of the brackets are strictly necessary, but I usually prefer to use them rather than remember whether `AND` or `OR` has higher precedence.

Answer (score 3):

To parse contditions into SQL one may use a simple set of two rules:

1. Change "then fetch Rate" to "OR (...)"
2. Change "then" to "AND (...)"

so the resulting SQL is something like that:

```
select Rate
  from ...
 where (X > Y) OR
          (A > B) AND 
            ((C > D) OR 
             (E > F) AND 
               ((G > H) OR 
                (I > J) OR 
                (K > L) AND 
                   (M > N)))
```

Comment: I am trying to convert this into SQL.. Thanks for reply.